# Android project showing up with a duplicate app upon deployment

Tags: android, android-studio

My directory structure is as follows:

```
Project
--libraries
----volley
--myapplication
----libs
------android-support-v4.jar
------etc.jar
```

Volley is an imported library project. Everything runs fine with the application, but when it's installed, 2 different apps show up on the android app list with the same name and icon. One of them works as expected, and the other seems to be some empty activity and crashes upon execution with the error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.myapplication/com.libs.volley.ACTIVITY_ENTRY_NAME}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.libs.volley.ACTIVITY_ENTRY_NAME" on path: /data/app/com.example.myapplication-1.apk
```

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding and uninstalling from the device itself, to no avail. All I would like to do is to get rid of this extra app.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapplication"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name=".AppConfigActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:label="Application configuration"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".BoothSelectActivity"
        android:label="Booth Select"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".InactiveActivity"
        android:label="Inactive Activity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".QRReaderActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:label="QR Reader Activity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ProductsActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:label="Products Activity"/>

</application>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

My build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:volley')
}

task copyNativeLibs(type: Copy) {
    from(new File('src/main/libs')) { include '**' }
    into new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')
}

tasks.withType(Compile) { compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn copyNativeLibs }

clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyNativeLibs'

tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniDir new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')
}
```

My settings.gradle

```
include  ':myapplicationname', ':libraries:volley'
```

Comment: Do you have the source code for the library project? It is likely that the library project has its own 'launcher' defined in its manifest.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, you were correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If an imported library has an Activity that also contains a launcher, it will create another application.  To prevent this, make sure no other Activities have the following marks in the AndroidManifest of each project.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: In my case, I had to go into `\build\intermediates\exploded-aar` and edit the AndroidManifest of that library (which had a demo app). I removed the whole `intent-filter` tag but kept the `activity` tag. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check on the file Project/.idea/modules.xml and remove the second module you don't want to show up.

The file should look like this.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project version="4">
        <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
            <modules>
                <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/module2.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/module2.iml" />
                <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/module1.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/module1.iml" />
            </modules>
        </component>
    </project>`